# JPQL query does not return proper output, throws error

Tags: java, jpql

The following query throws me an error

```
@GET
@Path("findByStartEndVari/{startdate}/{enddate} ")
@Produces({"application/json"})


public List<Dailyrecords> findByStartEndVari(@PathParam("startdate") Date startdate, @PathParam("enddate") Date enddate)        

{

    TypedQuery<Dailyrecords> q = em.createQuery("SELECT d.painlevel,  d.painlocation FROM Dailyrecords d WHERE d.submitdate BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate ", Dailyrecords.class);
    q.setParameter("startdate", startdate);
            q.setParameter("enddate", enddate);

    return q.getResultList();

}
```

- It gives an output when I use SELECT d instead of particular attributes.
  Throws a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Have you ascertained that you can connect to your database from Java?

Comment: Yes! I even get output if I use SELECT d FROM Dailyrecords. It throws an error only when I select Few particular attributes.

Comment: can you paste stacktrace here

Comment: Please post your `Dailyrecords` class also.

Comment: No stack trace is thrown in Netbeans."GET RequestFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (500) 
Response: {
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Status report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. " I get this in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current syntax is incorrect.  If you want your JPQL query to return a `DailyRecords` object then you need to select the entire object:

```
TypedQuery<Dailyrecords> q = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dailyrecords d WHERE d.submitdate BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate ", Dailyrecords.class);
q.setParameter("startdate", startdate);
q.setParameter("enddate", enddate);
```

If you really want only specified columns, then you can try the following:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT d.painlevel,  d.painlocation FROM Dailyrecords d WHERE d.submitdate BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate");
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
```

When you query individual columns, you will get back an `Object[]`, with each entry in the array corresponding to one column.  So in this case, the first entry would be the pain level, and the second the pain location.

Comment: This query does work but what should I do in case I need only 2 of the attributes in the table and not the whole table itself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try and get back.